# How to implement an updated controller.rb file into Restful Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't have much experience with Rails. I can tell that just saving the controller ruby file doesn't implement the changes. Do I need to run some specific command prompt lines on the server? Which ones for rails version 4.1.5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which controller are you changing? Usually changes to controller code go into effect as soon as you save them but if you are in doubt you can always stop the server (Ctrl + C from the terminal window running the server) and start it back up again.

Some changes require a server restart but most don't.

Comment: Schedule_controller.rb
I try restarting the whole server next.

Comment: @JCLee Are you sure it's not called schedules_controller.rb? Controller names are supposed to be plural. That might be part of your problem if that is indeed the name.

Comment: Restarting the whole server worked. Restarting the associated Windows service or task schedule does nothing.

Comment: Nope, there is no 'schedules_controller'.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you. I would recommend following the Rails controller naming conventions though. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html for more info on the benefits of following the standards. Cheers!